# My tinyMCE textarea is inside a jQuery UI tab. tinyMCE loads but it won't allow me to type. Why?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

Assuming I already called the necessary codes for jQuery UI, jQuery and tinyMCE:

Initialize tinyMCE (included in main.html):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    editor_selector: "tinyMCE",
    theme: "simple"
});
```

Code segment for jQuery UI tabs (included in main.html):

```
<div id="myTab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">Tab 1 content</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <textarea class="tinyMCE">Textarea content</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery UI code for making a tab (included in a separate file: functions.js):

```
$("#myTab").tabs();
```

The tinyMCE textarea successfully loads, but the problem is, I cannot type anything in it. The buttons are not functioning as well. What might be the problem here and what should be the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, I tried putting the tinyMCE textarea outside the jQuery UI tab, and it worked. So I guess the cause of the problem is the jquery ui tab. But I believe there must be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/Zzum9/) with your code and it works.
I've used the latest versions of everything.
Which versions are you using?
Can you create a jsfiddle test?